# Recursively Access Item In Python Dictionary of Unknown Dimensions

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary

I'm trying to take a list of objects and rearrange them into a dictionary of nested dictionaries based on the objects' "keys."  Each key contains the key of its parent dictionary in a known pattern.  The problem I'm running into is being able to access an element like...

```
hier_data['1']['Assets']['1.2']['Assets']['1.2.3']['Assets']['1.2.3.4']['Assets']
```

...dynamically so as to add to it.  Is there a way to build some sort of recursive function that will traverse down the dictionary based on the key?  For example, if I needed to add the object with the key '1.2.3.4.5', is there a way to do...

```
hier_data['1']['Assets']['1.2']['Assets']['1.2.3']['Assets']['1.2.3.4']['Assets']['1.2.3.4.5'] = {...}
```

...dynamically and recursively?

I should note that the list I'm starting from is sorted by key so that I should always have the current object's parent's 'Assets' dictionary available for adding to.

Comment: Sure, but... why would you store it like that instead of just `hier_data['1.2.3.4.5']['Assets']`?

Comment: This is a fragile data structure. Consider a tree...

Comment: @DavidRobinson, I'm trying to output nested JSON of the data structure so I can draw nested <li>s on the client side.

Comment: @drewk, what do you mean by a "tree"?  I'm sure there's a better way to do this, I just don't know any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what I was having trouble with was simpler than I thought.  All I needed to do was something like this:

```
hier_data = {}
for id in sorted(data.iterkeys()):
  key = id.split('.')
  data[id]['Assets'] = {}
  insert_point = hier_data
  for i in range(len(key)/2-1):
    insert_point = insert_point['.'.join(key[0:2*i+2])]['Assets']
  insert_point[id] = data[id]
return hier_data
```

I thought getting keys from dictionaries (e.g. `hier_data[...]`) would return a copy of the object at that point in the dictionary, not a pointer to the object.  Turns out all I needed was to iterate over my broken-up key to move my `insert_point` cursor to the correct spot to add in my object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive `defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> l = lambda: defaultdict(l)
>>> d = defaultdict(l)
>>> d['123']['4234']['asd']['dsaf'] = 4
>>> d
    defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x15f9578>, {'123': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x15f9578>, {'4234': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x15f9578>, {'asd': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x15f9578>, {'dsaf': 4})})})})
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know about defaultdict.  And it would be helpful, except that my keys are sorted, so I'm never going to run into a situation in which I don't have a parent key for a particular entry.  What I'm really looking for is how to get the chain of assignment ['1']['23']['456']['7890']... dynamically without having to have each of those brackets in code.  Also, I found this elegant way of writing it while learning this: https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250